# Array initialization in class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I try to create a date class and would like to set array in it as:

```
class Date {
private:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int daysPerMonth[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
};
```

Compiler gives an error that it is forbidden to use array like this. How can I do this?

Comment: use a constructor to initialize the variables.

Comment: In-class initializer now is supported in c++11, try g++ -o m main.cpp -std=c++11

Comment: Yeap, it work if initialize in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Array initialisation for class members (in-place, or with initializer lists) is a new feature in C++11.  If you have compiler that supports the updated language, you can use the following syntax:

```
class Date {
private:
    int daysPerMonth[12] {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
};
```

However, in the case of *days per month* it might be a little pointless (assuming you are only supporting the Gregorian calendar), because that kind of thing tends to be declared as `static const` (these values should never change and do not need multiple instances), which would allow the data to be initialised easily using language features that predate C++11.  *eg*

```
// In the header
class Date {
private:
    static int const daysPerMonth[12];
};

// And in the implementation file
int const Date::daysPerMonth[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
```